# requests-html: Unresolved attribute reference 'html' for class 'Response'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, python-requests-html

Good day!

Can anyone please give me a hint, why PyCharm thinks  return of `s.get('https://www.httpbin.org')` function is a `Response` object? It should be a`HTMLResponse` instad.

> Unresolved attribute reference 'html' for class 'Response'

Code is here:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession

s = HTMLSession()
r = s.get('https://www.httpbin.org')
r.html.render(sleep=5, timeout=10)
print(r.status_code)
```

Although, if I do `print(type(r))` it will return `<class 'requests_html.HTMLResponse'>`.

What went wrong? How to fix it?
That is not a critical issue, but annying for sure.

Comment: Its probably just a reference error in pycharms library skeletons. I get it sometimes for other libraries as well. It does not affect your code, so I would not do anything about it. Otherwise you could write to either pycharm people or the people who make requests_html.

Comment: It can be mistake in PyCharm, not in Python, so if you can run without error messages then don't bother this.